# Inconsistent "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, variable-expansion

I guess I'm mad enough to use a batch file, in the first place, but this problem has me tearing my hair out! The below batch script *usually* works just fine. However, on first run it will give a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error; and it will do this until I `REM` out everything, run it through, and then un`REM` it. Then it magically starts working again!

```
@echo off

REM Create processed data directory
set "PROCDIR=processed"
mkdir %PROCDIR% 2>nul

REM Loop through CSV files and process them
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  set "in=%%~nf"
  set "input=%%~nxf"
  set "out_lang=%PROCDIR%\%in%_lang.csv"
  set "out_spr=%PROCDIR%\%in%_spr.csv"
  set "out_ajt=%PROCDIR%\%in%_ajt.csv"

  echo Processing %input%

  REM Split input file appropriately
  REM FIXME Hardcoded line ranges are brittle
  sed -n "1,2p"  %input% > %out_lang%
  sed -n "3,55p" %input% > %out_spr%.tmp
  sed -n "56,$p" %input% > %out_ajt%.tmp

  REM Unpack SPR data
  REM n.b., Needs gawk 4, or later
  gawk -f spr.awk %out_spr%.tmp > %out_spr%
  del %out_spr%.tmp

  REM Substitute AJT data values
  REM n.b., -i seems to be buggy in Windows
  sed -f ajt.sed %out_ajt%.tmp > %out_ajt%
  del %out_ajt%.tmp
)
```

If I `REM` out the `@echo off`, it appears it's failing because the variable substitution sometimes -- for unknown reasons -- doesn't work. Then, when it gets to `sed`, it just gives up.

I assume I'm missing something... Any ideas what it might be!? (Besides my marbles!)

Comment: Nothing funny, just alphanumeric with underscores and dashes (but it even baulks on `test.csv`!). I'll check for the BOM, but I'm pretty sure it's just straight up UTF-8; and I don't see anything in there that would make it indistinguishable from ASCII-7, if that also makes the difference... Thanks for the tip off :)

Comment: if a script behaves different the first time than in the following runs, it's usually a strong hint for the [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) (yes - I see, that's your Problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I could give advice, use and abuse the `PAUSE` command, `ECHO` and escape characters `^` in it. Also Ctrl-C to stop the script during a `PAUSE`.

Here is a debugged version:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL
REM Create processed data directory
set "PROCDIR=processed"
echo mkdir %PROCDIR% 2^>nul

REM Loop through CSV files and process them
for %%F in (*.csv) do (
  set "in=%%~nF"
  echo in: %in%
  set "input=%%~nxF"
  echo input: %input%
  set "out_lang=%PROCDIR%\%in%_lang.csv"
  set "out_spr=%PROCDIR%\%in%_spr.csv"
  set "out_ajt=%PROCDIR%\%in%_ajt.csv"

  echo Processing %input%
PAUSE

  REM Split input file appropriately
  REM FIXME Hardcoded line ranges are brittle
  echo sed -n "1,2p"  %input% ^> %out_lang%
  echo sed -n "3,55p" %input% ^> %out_spr%.tmp
  echo sed -n "56,$p" %input% ^> %out_ajt%.tmp
PAUSE

  REM Unpack SPR data
  REM n.b., Needs gawk 4, or later
  echo gawk -f spr.awk %out_spr%.tmp ^> %out_spr%
  echo del %out_spr%.tmp
PAUSE

  REM Substitute AJT data values
  REM n.b., -i seems to be buggy in Windows
  echo sed -f ajt.sed %out_ajt%.tmp ^> %out_ajt%
  echo del %out_ajt%.tmp
PAUSE

)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF
EXIT /B 0
```

I added `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and this seems to solve undeclared variable errors.

Here is a working version (you have to remove every redundant `echo` and carets `^`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Create processed data directory
set "PROCDIR=processed"
echo mkdir %PROCDIR% 2^>nul

REM Loop through CSV files and process them
for %%F in (*.csv) do (
  set "in=%%~nF"
  echo in: !in!
  set "input=%%~nxF"
  echo input: !input!
  set "out_lang=!PROCDIR!\!in!_lang.csv"
  set "out_spr=!PROCDIR!\!in!_spr.csv"
  set "out_ajt=!PROCDIR!\!in!_ajt.csv"

  echo Processing !input!
PAUSE

  REM Split input file appropriately
  REM FIXME Hardcoded line ranges are brittle
  echo sed -n "1,2p"  !input! ^> !out_lang!
  echo sed -n "3,55p" !input! ^> !out_spr!.tmp
  echo sed -n "56,$p" !input! ^> !out_ajt!.tmp
PAUSE

  REM Unpack SPR data
  REM n.b., Needs gawk 4, or later
  echo gawk -f spr.awk !out_spr!.tmp ^> !out_spr!
  echo del !out_spr!.tmp
PAUSE

  REM Substitute AJT data values
  REM n.b., -i seems to be buggy in Windows
  echo sed -f ajt.sed !out_ajt!.tmp ^> !out_ajt!
  echo del !out_ajt!.tmp
PAUSE

)
endlocal
GOTO :EOF
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 1):

[Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) is right, batch code is not working because of not using delayed expansion within **FOR** loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Create processed data directory
set "PROCDIR=processed"
mkdir "%PROCDIR%" 2>nul

REM Loop through CSV files and process them
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  set "in=%%~nf"
  set "input=%%~nxf"
  set "out_lang=%PROCDIR%\!in!_lang.csv"
  set "out_spr=%PROCDIR%\!in!_spr.csv"
  set "out_ajt=%PROCDIR%\!in!_ajt.csv"

  echo Processing !input!

  REM Split input file appropriately
  REM FIXME Hardcoded line ranges are brittle
  sed -n "1,2p"  "!input!" >"!out_lang!"
  sed -n "3,55p" "!input!" >"!out_spr!.tmp"
  sed -n "56,$p" "!input!" >"!out_ajt!.tmp"

  REM Unpack SPR data
  REM n.b., Needs gawk 4, or later
  gawk -f spr.awk "!out_spr!.tmp" >"!out_spr!"
  del "!out_spr!.tmp"

  REM Substitute AJT data values
  REM n.b., -i seems to be buggy in Windows
  sed -f ajt.sed "!out_ajt!.tmp" >"!out_ajt!"
  del "!out_ajt!.tmp"
)
endlocal
```

Every environment variable referenced within a block defined by `(` ... `)` is expanded by command processor already on parsing the entire block. On one of the help pages output into a command prompt window on execution of `if /?` explains that in detail.

This could been seen on running the batch code in question without the first line from within a command prompt window. Running a batch file from within a command prompt window without `echo off` or with `echo on` should be used on debugging batch code not working as expected.

And in case of any CSV file in current directory contains 1 or more spaces in file name, it is necessary to enclose all file references in double quotes to have a working code also for such files.